# Transform not working properly on anchor

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to animate a button making it translate a little bit to the right for a specific time, but somehow the transition never happens.

```css
@keyframes moveXpath {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}

.btn-animate {
  animation-name: moveXpath;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>button animation</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#" class="btn-animate">rotating button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

lost some time and can't figure out what is wrong any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor are inline elements transform does not work on these type of elements.

Add a different display (block or inline-block) to your anchor

```
.btn-animate {
    animation-name: moveXpath;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Source: [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element)

Comment: can you explain it ?

Comment: @caxinaswin check the edited answer if it's still not clear hit me up!

Comment: hmmm got it, they have no space to apply the transform makes sense, thanks :)